# wkhtmltoimage Segmentation Fault (core dumped) . The error came with some particular url

Tags: segmentation-fault, wkhtmltoimage

shttp://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.11.0_rc1-static-amd64.tar.bz2

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/detail?name=wkhtmltoimage-0.11.0_rc1-static-i386.tar.bz2

I've tried with both above wkhtml2image versions and I got same result:

"wkhtmltoimage-i386 --disable-javascript --disable-plugins http://apple.com test.jpg"

Loading page (1/2)
Rendering (2/2)
QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used   ] 25%
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The strange thing is the plugin worked fine on some web site url such as google.com, wordpress.com, but not on some url such as:
apple.com, paypal.com, linkedin.com, ....

I tried add some flags to disable javascript like some guys said on http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=786 but it took no any effect.

My server info: CentOS 6.3. 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I install virtual X11 Server to solved this issue. The tutorial which I found is below
http://tech.gluga.com/2012/09/screenshot-webpage-via-command-line.html